# CSS3 animations don't always run when 'display' attribute is set on a pseudo element

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

The problem I am running into occurs when trying to animate a web font. Specifically, if the HTML element has a class that defines the `font-family` and other needed CSS attributes on the `:before` element as opposed to the element itself, the pseudo content will **not** get animated.

Here is some sample CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: /** src urls here... **/
}

.fa-before:before,
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-refresh:before {
  content: "\f021";
}

.spinning-loader {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Now the key part is my `fa` and `fa-before:before` selectors.

If I use the `fa-before` class, that works fine to set the correct `font-family` of my `:before` content. Additionally, plain `fa` also works fine for the `:before` content (and I think any other content too).

The problem is, if an element has `fa-before`, it doesn't animate (at least, not *all* browsers animate it).

```
<!-- This doesn't always animate -->
<i class="fa-before icon-refresh spinning-loader"></i>

<!-- This DOES always animate -->
<i class="fa icon-refresh spinning-loader"></i>
```

When it works:

[image: When it works]

When it doesn't work:

[image: When it doesn't work]

Here is a JSFiddle so you can test in your own browser: https://jsfiddle.net/b3gojahs/1/

Here are all the browsers I've been able to test:

1. **Works in:**

   - Mac OS X 10.10.5

     - Chrome 47.0.2526.111
   - Windows 10.0.10240

     - IE 11.0.10240.16644
     - Edge 10.10240.16384.0
2. **Doesn't work in:**

   - Mac OS X 10.10.5

     - Chrome Canary 50.0.2639.0 (!!)
     - Safari 9.0.3 (10601.4.4)
     - Firefox 44.0
   - Windows 10.0.10240

     - Chrome 48.0.2564.97
     - Firefox 44.0

Anyone know why this is occurring? I can't seem to find any articles on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does the animation not work when fa-before class is applied?**

The problem is because [`i` element is an inline element by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) and CSS transforms don't work on inline elements. Inline elements are not transformable elements.

> As per [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering):
>
> Transforms apply to transformable elements.
>
> **transformable element**
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>   an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is ***either a block-level or atomic inline-level element***, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
>
> **atomic inline-level element**
>
> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes because they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque box.

When the `fa` class is applied on the element, the element's display is changed to `inline-block` via the CSS and so the animation that is applied through `.spinning-loader` selector works as expected.

However when the `fa-before` class is applied on the element, only the `:before` pseudo-element of the `i` gets the display changed to `inline-block`. The display setting of the `i` itself doesn't change and it remains as the default `inline` setting. Because of this, the animation on the `i` has no effect.

---

**What is the solution?**

Solution is exactly the same that is mentioned in [Paulie_D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35183702/2606013). The parent `i` element on which the transform animation is applied should be made as a block or an inline-block element.

```
i.spinning-loader {display: inline-block;} /* this setting should solve it */
```

<sup>**Note:** The behavior in Chrome is a bit erratic (atleast on my PC - v43 + Win 7). It starts working automatically when I make any change to the fiddle, close and then reopen it. I have no explanation for this but Firefox is perfect.</sup>

---

**Why does it work on some browsers?**

This is something to which I don't have an answer at present. The only reason could be that they treat the `i` element differently and set its default display setting as block or inline-block.

Comment: Excellent, this kind of insight was exactly what I was hoping someone would be able to provide. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be setting the

```
.fa-before:before{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Is you just make this

```
.fa-before {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

It works just fine - [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/b3gojahs/3/)

Comment: Thanks, that does fix the issue. However, do you know of any documentation detailing this? That is, why does setting that fix the issue?

Comment: Not offhand I'd have to do some more research.