# CSS text wiggle animation no longer works on Chrome/Firefox but works on Edge

Tags: html, css

This is the website in question : http://dilanianart.me/

I built it about 8 months ago (first website ever made) and it had a wiggle animation similar to the one shown here:

[CSS Text Wiggle](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/css/css3-wiggle-on-hover-demo.php)

The animation in the link below is working on all three major browsers... so I know there is something now wrong with my css code (though I did not change anything since before).

The animation used to work, now I logged back on the site and it is no longer working on my webpage.

You can also view all the source code by browsing the page since it is a static website.

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
         <a href=index.html>DilanianArt.me</a>
      </div>
      <div id="nav">
         <li><a href=info.html class="wiggle-me">Info</a></li>
         <li><a href=flora.html class="wiggle-me">Flora</a></li>
         <li><a href=legends.html class="wiggle-me">Legends</a></li>
         <li><a href=portraits.html class="wiggle-me">Portraits</a></li>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
         <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
               <li>
                  <img class="index" src="images/portraits/1.jpg" alt=" ">
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img class="index" src="images/legends/2.jpg" alt=" ">
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img class="index" src="images/flora/9.jpg" alt=" ">
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img class="index" src="images/portraits/4.jpg" alt=" ">
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img class="index" src="images/flora/2.jpg" alt=" ">
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
         <li>Copyrights 1-1985043901 Registered VAu001195524</li>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@-ms-keyframes wiggle {
   0% {
      -ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
   50% {
      -ms-transform:rotate(-2deg);
   }
   100% {
      -ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
}

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
   0% {
      -moz-transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
   50% {
      -moz-transform:rotate(-2deg);
   }
   100% {
      -moz-transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
   50% {
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);
   }
   100% {
      -webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
}

@keyframes wiggle {
   0% {
      transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
   50% {
      transform:rotate(-2deg);
   }
   100% {
      transform:rotate(2deg);
   }
}


a.wiggle-me:hover {
   -ms-animation: wiggle .7s 30;
   -moz-animation: wiggle .7s 30;
   -webkit-animation: wiggle .7s 30;
   animation: wiggle .7s 30;
}
```

Comment: Your website doesn't work for me and it crashes every time I try to inspect it via Dev Tools but I have a feeling that the animation isn't working because the element is `inline` (`a` elements are inline by default). CSS transforms don't work on `inline` elements like I had mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183494/css3-animations-dont-always-run-when-display-attribute-is-set-on-a-pseudo-ele/35192803#35192803 Check if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a few more vendor prefixes in the animation chains to make it really cross-browser.

```
.wiggle-me {
   display: inline-block;
}

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
   0% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
   }
   50% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
   }
   100% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); 
     transform: rotate(2deg);
   }
   50% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); 
     transform: rotate(-2deg);
   }
   100% {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); 
     transform: rotate(2deg);
   }
}

@keyframes wiggle {
   0% {
     -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); 
     transform: rotate(2deg);
   }
   50% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); 
     transform: rotate(-2deg);
   }
   100% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); 
     transform: rotate(2deg);
   }
}
```

Comment: that did not work... neither did copying the css code from this link: http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/css/css3-wiggle-on-hover.php which does in fact work on chrome. so there is something in my web page preventing it from working in chrome and firefox, any ideas?

Comment: Looked at your code again. Try setting the links to inline block ( .wiggle-me { display:inline-block; }. Transforms don't work on inline elements (according to the specs). Added it also in the code above!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the vendor prefix for webkit in the keyframe:

```
@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
 0% {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
 }
 50% {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
 }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: That was my mistake I copied the wrong code. But on the website which I linked it contains the proper css format